# replace row of 3D array if all values below test - one numpy line using indexing

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a numpythonic way to do this? Original array is of dimension `N x M x 3`, I'd like to make a `N x M` mask as shown. I thought there was a simple way to write this with Numpy but I'm having brain freeze.

While there may be alternative ways to implement this, I'm trying to do it this way to maintain my skills at using Numpy indexing.

This fails because `img2[test]` looses the original shape. Do I have to `.reshape()` somehow, or is there simpler way where I don't need to explicitly restate the dimensions of the axes?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img  = np.random.random(100*100*3).reshape(100, 100, -1)
img2 = img.copy()

target = np.array([0.5, 0.3, 0.7])

test = np.abs(img - target) < 0.5

img2[test] = np.zeros(3)  # probem, img2[test] looses its shape

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.hstack((img, img2)))
plt.show()

File "/Users/yournamehere/Documents/fishing/Eu;er diagram/stackexchange question v00.py", line 12, in <module>
    img2[test] = target
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 11918 output values where the mask is true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner showcasing the very useful `keepdims` kwarg

```
np.where(np.logical_and.reduce(test, axis=-1, keepdims=True), [0, 0, 0], img)
```

Comment: Thank you for the mini numpyphany! It isn't every day one can learn several new things from a one-line answer.

Comment: @uhoh Thanks! Glad you're enjoying it.

Answer (score 0):

Brain has un-frozen. Forgot to use `.all()` to collape the test to a single boolean value for each `N x M` location. Once that is corrected, Numpy does it's thing very nicely.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img  = np.random.random(100*100*3).reshape(100, 100, -1)
img2 = img.copy()

target = np.array([0.5, 0.3, 0.7])

test = (np.abs(img - target) < 0.5).all(axis=-1)

img2[test] = np.zeros(3)  # probem, img2[test] looses its shape

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.hstack((img, img2)))
plt.show()
```